# Prove or disprove: if $g(n)<f(n)$ then exists $h(n)>g(n)$ and $f(n)>h(n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, asymptotics

> Let $f,g,h:\mathbb N\to \mathbb N$ be increasing functions ($0\notin \mathbb N$).
>
> If $\forall c>0\quad \exists n_0 \in \mathbb N$ such that $\forall n>n_0:f(n)>g(n)$ then there exists $h(n)$ such that $h(n)>g(n)$ and $f(n)>h(n)$.
>
> Prove or disprove. We're interested in asymptotic behavior that when $n\to\infty$.

I think it's true because of $>$ is transitive although maybe it doesn't always hold true in infinity.

From the given:
$$
 f(n)>c\cdot g(n)\Rightarrow 1)\quad \exists h(n)>{1\over c}g(n)\\
\text{and}\qquad 2)\quad  f(n)>({1\over c-k})g(n) \qquad c>k
$$ 
For 1) it's trivial that $c>{1\over c}$.

For 2) because $f(n)>g(n)$ then:
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=\infty\Rightarrow \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{f(n)}{({1\over c-k})g(n)}=(c-k)\cdot \infty=\infty
$$
Does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false. Consider 
$$
f(n) = n\\
g(n) = n-1.
$$
Then for all $c$, pick $n_0 = 1$. There's no "room" for $h(n)$ between $f(n)$ and $g(n)$.

If the codomain were $\Bbb R$, you could pick $h(n) = (f(n) + g(n))/2$.

Comment: But is $g(n)<f(n)$ asymptotically in your example? Their limits both evaluate to infinity.

Comment: What does "$g(n) < f(n)$ asymptotically" mean to you precisely? It doesn't mean anything at all to me, so I'm confused. Certainly $g$ and $f$ meet all the requirements of your question as phrased. (Pick $n_0 = 0$.)

Comment: For me it means the value of the function when $n \to \infty$. So the premise is that $g<f$. Given the functions you suggested: $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n-1}{n}=1$ which means that the functions are of the same order asymptotically. For example $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n}{n^2}=0$ which means that asymptotically $n^2$ is strictly greater than $n$

Comment: "The value of the function when $n \to \infty$" makes no sense to me. (And I say that as someone who has actually taught real analysis.) I mean, there's an intuitive notion, sure. But give me a rigoroous definition. Saying "$g < f$" just leads to the question "what does "<" mean for functions?" It could be pointwise less-than? big-O less-than? less-than almost everywhere? Until you specify, it means nothing. (And your question, as written, said nothing about $g < f$; it just said $g(n) < f(n)$ for every sufficiently large $n$. So that's why I gave the answer that I did.)

Comment: The conditions correspond to the definition of $g=o(f)$ which is little-O in the big-O notation. I did mention that we're interested in asymptotic behavior so the fact that $g(1)<f(1)$ is not relevant

Comment: No, it does *not* correspond to that -- you've mistranslated the definition of little-$o$. (One way to see this: the $c$ in your universal quantifier appears nowhere else!) But my answer (and Robert Z.'s) are both correct answers to the question you mistakenly DID ask.

Comment: Yes I think I forgot to add $c$ inside the inequality. It should've been like this $\forall c>0\quad \exists n_0 \in \mathbb N$ such that $\forall n>n_0:cf(n)>g(n)$ right?

Comment: How the heck should *I* know if that's what you wanted to say? If it *is* what you wanted, you should ask a different question rather than modifying this one after it's already got correct answers.

Comment: Well, you said I've "mistranslated" the definition so you must know the correct definition if you claim so. And I'm not going to change the question.

Comment: I know the correct definition of little-o; I don't know how you *intended* to use it. Best of luck getting an answer to your eventual question.

Answer (score 2):

The statement is false. Take $f(n)=n+1$ and $g(n)=n$. Is there any integer valued $h$ strictly between $g$ and $f$?

P.S. Note that if we allow that the values of $h$ are in $\mathbb{Q}$ then we may take $h(n)=\frac{g(n)+f(n)}{2}$.

Comment: Of course, I completely ignored that we're over natural numbers.

Comment: Come to think of it is your $f(n)>g(n)$ asymptotically? The limits of both $f$ and $g$ are the same